# ANNs in Matlab and FANN

Tags: .net, matlab

How can I get a neural net file from Matlab into a FANN .net file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, MATLAB bindings for FANN exist and you can find them at http://leenissen.dk/fann/
However, you can create a script which convert data withing MATLAB ANN structure into a correct FANN configuration file. You have only to "translate" the parameters..